# Execute link from external html file

Tags: html, filter, hyperlink

I have 2 html files:

- index.html
- portfolio.html

In portfolio.html I have 4 categories of my work: web, 3d, codes and video. Also I have included a filter script which shows only the work of the category which is selected and it's working.

In index.html I need to have links which directs to each category of my portfolio, but I don't know how to do this.

Here are the codes:

Index.html:

```
...
<a href="portfolio.html#web"><img src="img/web.png"></a>
<a href="portfolio.html#triD"><img src="img/triD.png"></a>
<a href="portfolio.html#codes"><img src="img/codes.png"></a>
<a href="portfolio.html#video"><img src="img/video.png"></a>
...
```

Portfolio.html:

```
...
<!-- filter goes here: -->
<p id="picker">
    <a href="#" id="all" class="current" name="all">All</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="web" class="filter" name="web">Web</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="triD" class="filter" name="triD">3D</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="codes" class="filter" name="codes">Codes</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="video" class="filter" name="video">Video</a>
</p>

<!-- my work goes here: -->
<div class="my-work codes">...</div>
<div class="my-work web">...</div>
<div class="my-work triD">...</div>
<div class="my-work codes">...</div>
...
```

Filter.js:

```
$(function()
{   
   $("#all").click(function(){
       $(".my-work").slideDown();
       $("#catpicker a").removeClass("current");
       $(this).addClass("current");
       return false;
   });

   $(".filter").click(function(){
        var thisFilter = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".my-work").slideUp();
        $("."+ thisFilter).slideDown();
        $("#catpicker a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        return false;
   });

});
```

Comment: This is a javascript question, not an HTML question. How to do what you're asking, or whether it's even possible, depends entirely on how the filter script you're using works. Please post the script.

Comment: I have added the filter.js script (it's written in jQuery). At this moment it's only included in portfolio.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have found the right answer of my question.
In portfolio.html, after all scripts in the header, it should be added the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var type = window.location.hash;
    //window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(type,''); //should be added if you want to remove: ...#class in address bar
    $(type).trigger('click');
});
```